# Overcounting in combinatorics problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Disclaimer: this is a homework exercise, please don't give me the full solution! I'd just like a hint in the right direction.

```
A box contains 30 red balls, 30 white balls, and 30 blue
balls. If 10 balls are selected at random, without replacement,
what is the probability that at least one color will be
missing from the selection?
```

My reasoning so far has been to look at the event that every colour is present, and then just do $1 - $ that value. We can think of it as selecting 3 balls, one from each colour, and then filling the remaining 7 spaces with any other balls. Selecting 1 ball from 30 three times is $30^3$ combinations. Then, selecting 7 balls from 87 is $C_7^{87}$ combinations, and the total combinations is their product. However, this turns out to be larger than $C_{10}^{90}$, which is the total amount of ways 10 balls can be selected from 90 balls.

Clearly, I've overcounted somewhere, but I have no idea where! I've been stuck on this for hours and I can't see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: The ways to select 10 balls with no color missed can be counted by the total number of possible ways to select 10 balls minus the ways to select 10 balls of at most 2 colors. So, the number of ways is, $$\binom{90}{10}-\left(3\binom{60}{10}+3\binom{30}{10}\right)$$

Comment: **Thank you** for that first paragraph.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas, why not just post an answer?  That *is* the answer.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas The very first paragraph of the question states, "this is a homework exercise, please don't give me the full solution! I'd just like a hint in the right direction." This question has not been edited, so that sentence was surely there when you posted your comment. Yet your comment directly ignores this and provides a full solution. Please consider deleting your comment, and reading more carefully in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's try a similar problem with smaller numbers; then we can actually list all the possibilities and see which ones we've counted twice.

Suppose there are $3$ balls: 2 red balls and one blue ball. How many ways can we draw two balls (without replacement) so that at least one is red? Call the balls $r_1,r_2,$ and $b.$

**Correct solution:** There are three ways to draw two balls: $r_1r_2,r_1b,r_2b$, and every one of them has at least one red ball, so the answer is $3.$

**Incorrect solution:** We need at least one red ball, so start by drawing a red ball: $2$ possibilities. Then draw a second ball, we don't care what color it is: $2$ possibilities. So the answer is $2\times2=4.$ ***What went wrong?*** The $4$ combinations we counted are $r_1r_2,r_1b,r_2r_1,r_2b.$ ***Oops***, the case "draw both red balls" was counted twice!

Your mistake was where you said "We can think of it as selecting 3 balls, one from each colour, and then filling the remaining 7 spaces with any other balls."

Comment: The best answer posted as it actually addresses the problem in OP's argument. +1

Answer (score 1):

hint: are the balls of each color distinguishable ?

Comment: No they are not! So I need to divide by 3!, right?

Comment: no you need to do cases and divide by the factorials of how many are of each color in each case.

Comment: an example application of this is in chess if you want to rearrange the back row of the board for each player how many positions for each player are there ? permutations would make you think 8! but without further restrictions you can say well the two knights on each side are indistinguishable and the two rooks are as well so there's not more than 8!/((2!)*(2!)) = 8!/4 = 2*7! = 10080 and that assumes no restrictions on the bishops etc.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of ways you can pick $10$ balls out of $90$ is $\binom{90}{10}$. In how many ways can you pick $10$ balls excluding one colour and two colours, respectively?

Comment: Thanks! That would be 60C10 and 30C10, which I then need to multiply by some factor to account for the fact that the colours are indistinguishable... right?

Comment: @Bluefire yes, that's right. See comment below for more details.

Comment: @Bluefire, you're right in your thinking that you need to multiply them by some factor but that's not to account for the fact you mention but rather how you choose the excluding colors. Since there are three colors, you can exclude $1$ or $2$ colors in $\binom 32=\binom 31=3$ ways, so you multiply them by 3 and subtract it from the total (unrestricted) number of ways.